# Elasticsearch term aggregation document count issue

Tags: elasticsearch

This the request I'm sending to ElasticSearch:

```
{
  "aggregations":{
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.string1":{
      "terms":{
        "field":"metainfos.string1",
        "missing":"null",
        "order":{
          "_count":"asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm asking for buckets on field `metainfos.string1` and ordering them by `_count`. This is the response:

```
{
  "took":7,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":{
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":3,
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"be9b29f3-37a5-11e6-a66a-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-06-22T11:27:25.531Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s1",  <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
              "s2"   <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"c3af0f64-37a5-11e6-a66a-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-06-22T12:30:01.625Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s1",    <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
              "s2"     <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"living_v1",
        "_type":"fuas",
        "_id":"ee790469-48f3-11e6-9f47-30b5c2122322",
        "_score":1.0,
        "_routing":"living_team",
        "_source":{
          "user":"living_team",
          "timestamp":"2016-07-13T13:33:41.231Z",
          "metainfos":{
            "string1":[
              "s2"    <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations":{
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.string1":{
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
      "buckets":[
        {
          "key":"s2",
          "doc_count":2       <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
        },
        {
          "key":"s1",
          "doc_count":3       <<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are two buckets: `s1` and `s2`. However, `s1` is present only in two documents but ES is telling me that `doc_count = 3`!!! Moreover, `s2` is present in three documents, but ES is telling me that `doc_count = 2`!!!!

I'm performing it using only one node.

Any ideas?

**MAPPING**

```
{
  "living_v1":{
    "mappings":{
      "fuas":{
        "properties":{
          "metainfos":{
            "properties":{
              "string1":{
                "type":"string"
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp":{
            "type":"date",
            "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "user":{
            "type":"string",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the query you used for those results? (only aggregations, no query?)

Comment: Also, what's the mapping of `metainfos` field?

Comment: You need to be doing a nested aggregation I believe

Comment: Yes, the request is only the aggregation. I've added the mapping on post.

Comment: Run this query and provide the output: `GET /living_v1/fuas/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": [
    "string1"
  ]
}`

Comment: Aren't aggregations placed after the hits? Like on the bottom of the json.